# Client/Server WCF Chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm Hosting WCF Service on the localhost and the client is running in the same host, it works well when running both on the same machine but when i install the client in another machine and trying to connect to the server it fails ... here is the configuration file for the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsDualBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Metadata" name="ChatService.ChatManager">
        <endpoint address="duplex" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualBinding"
          contract="ChatService.IChat" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2525/chat/" />
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1717/chat/" />-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

the client config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.10:2525/chat/duplex" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="ChatService.IChat" name="mgr" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

it gives me that error

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue

Comment: Please post the client machine's config as well.  Also, what is the error message you get when it fails?

Comment: If you're using this client config on the other machine, the problem is in your client endpoint - you're still referencing localhost, so the client is going to look for the service on the same machine.

Comment: sorry , i know that , this is an old config , i will change it

Comment: So it's not an address issue with localhost.  Is the firewall blocking port 2525?

Comment: Also, I don't see a `clientBaseAddress` attribute in the binding definition on your client (`NewBinding0`).

Comment: i disabled the firewall before testing , still gives me the same error

Comment: Try adding a `clientBaseAddress` to your binding in the client config, like `<binding name="NewBinding0" clientBaseAddress="http://machinename:port/myClient">`.  This sets up an address the server can connect to (unlike say NetTCP, HTTP is not duplex).

Comment: it gives me that error 
"
The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:00:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

Comment: i didn't change the timeout values, its the default values

Answer (score 0):

`wsDualHttpBinding` requires the client to establish an address that the service can connect to in order to provide callbacks.  This is done in the config file in the binding element, like this:

```
<wsDualHttpBinding name="NewBinding0"
                   clientBaseAddress="http://machine_name:port/Client/">
```

Since the client is on a different machine than the service, you'll need to specify the client's machine name.

See [WSDualHttpBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx) for more information on this binding.